# AttributeRouting conflicting parameter route with string route

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, attributerouting

I have two controllers, `ItemsController` and `SingleItemController` which both inherit from `ApiController`. Both have RoutePrefix `items/inventory` defined on the controllers, like so:

```
[RoutePrefix("items/inventory")]
```

I'm using AttributeRouting in Web API 2.2.

In `SingleItemController` I have the following route:

```
[Route("{itemReference}")]
[HttpGet]
public ItemDTO GetItem(string itemReference)
```

In `ItemsController` I have the following route:

```
[Route("all")]
[HttpGet]
public List<ItemDTO> GetAllItems(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo)
```

When I try to hit the `/items/inventory/all?dateFrom=2015-09-06&dateTo=2015-09-12` route, I get the following error:

> Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can
>   happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested
>   URL. The request has found the following matching controller types:
>   ItemAPI.Controllers.ItemsController
>   ItemAPI.Controllers.SingleItemController

So `{itemReference}` route is conflicting with `all` route. Why is this? I would think that it reserves first `all` route and then allows an optional string route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because it can't decide whether "all" is an item reference.
I had a similar issue recently where I had a controller with an "admin" route prefix.

To get round the issue I put a constraint on the parameter to ignore the word "admin".
So in your case you could do the following to ignore the word "all":

```
[Route("{itemReference:regex(^(?!all))})]
```